# Dependency Injection: call different services based on the environment

Tags: c#, .net-core, inversion-of-control

I'm building a .net core 3.1 web application and I'm experimenting with the builtin dependency injection.

I would like to inject a different service based on the runtime environment in which the application is running, I thought that I could use an attribute to define if the service is suitable for the environment, for example:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...

    services.AddTransient<IOperation, OperationDevelopment>();
    services.AddTransient<IOperation, OperationStaging>();
    services.AddTransient<IOperation, OperationProduction>();

    ...
}


public interface IOperation
{
    Guid OperationId { get; }
}

[Development]
public class OperationDevelopment : IOperation
{
}

[Staging]
public class OperationStaging : IOperation
{
}

[Production]
public class OperationProduction : IOperation
{
}
```

What should I do, skip the registration? Register all and then resolve the suitable service? Something that I missed?

If the .net core DI is too basic, what should I use?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
interface IOperationAttribute
{
}

[Development]
public class OperationDevelopment : IOperation
{
    public Guid OperationId { get; }
}

public class DevelopmentAttribute : Attribute, IOperationAttribute
{
}
```

Add a new extension for IServiceCollection

```
public static class AppServiceExtension
{    
    public static IServiceCollection AppOperationServices(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var typesWithOperationAttribute =
            from a in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
            from t in a.GetTypes()
            let attributes = t.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(IOperationAttribute), true)
            where attributes != null && attributes.Length > 0
            select new { Type = t };

        foreach (var item in typesWithOperationAttribute)
            services.AddTransient((Type)item.Type);

        return services;
    }
}
```

And in ConfigureServices just call

```
services.AppOperationServices();
```

Answer (score 6):

Can you use a simple if inside the method? Hope it helps

```
if (Environment.IsDevelopment())
{ 
    services.AddTransient<IOperation, OperationDevelopment>();
}
else
{
    services.AddTransient<IOperation, OperationProduction>();
}
```

Comment: There are Environment.IsStaging() and Environment.IsProduction() methods if it helps the author

Comment: Well your answer is good but it doesn't register or resolve the service based on the **attribute**.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose  in your appsettings.json,if you have configured the environment variable like this

```
"environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
```

then in **startup.cs** ,capture the environment variable value

```
 public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IWebHostEnvironment environment)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
            Environment = environment;  
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
        public IWebHostEnvironment Environment { get; }
```

In **configureServices** capture host environment configuration

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            string currentEnvironment= Environment.EnvironmentName;
            if(currentEnvironment== "Development")
            {
                services.AddTransient<IOperation, OperationDevelopment>();
            }
            else if (currentEnvironment == "Staging")
            {
                services.AddTransient<IOperation, OperationStaging>();
            }
            else if (currentEnvironment == "Production")
            {
                services.AddTransient<IOperation, OperationProduction>();
            }
        }
```

**IWebHostEnvironment**  is for .netcore 3.0 (IHostEnvironment is for .net core 2.2)